# AWS: how to import a SSL certificate in PFX format into AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a legitimate SSL certificate in PFX file format. I run the following command:

```
pkcs12 -in "c:\temp\my_ssl_certificate.pfx" -out "c:\temp\my_ssl_certificate.txt" -nodes
```

Then I went to import certificate into AWS. I pasted the content between "----BEGIN CERTIFICATE ---" and "---- END CERTIFICATE ----" into the "**Certificate body**" textbox, and pasted what is between "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" into the "**Certificate private key**" texbox. Both complained

```
The certificate private key (or body) provided is not in a valid PEM format
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You have to paste it with the tags. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you Kaushal for your help! It worked. I learnt something!

Comment: Glad that it helped. I posted it as a answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you have not included the tags. You should be pasting it with the tags **"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"** and **"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"**